# WinAppDeployCmd - Automatic Pair device

Tags: c#, deployment, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-mobile

In order to use WinAppDeployCmd services, I'm trying to pair automatically my device to the laptop. Currently I'm using a Microsoft UWP example (DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) that should do what I want, but when I do a "Basic Device Pairing" and start watcher my laptop isn't in the list. Is there something I should set on my laptop to let it visible to the device? Is there another way to automatic pair the Microsoft device? Normally, user should go in Settings -> Update & Security -> For Developers -> Pair and copying the code shown on the command line, but if you have a lot of devices this is a very long procedure.

Comment: You run the UWP example(DeviceEnumuerationAndPairing) on your device and your laptop doesn't list on the app, right? What's your device? Does your laptop open the bluetooth?

Comment: My device is a Microsoft Lumia. If I active Bluetooth the device pair correctly, but I can't use WinAppDeployCmd services. I'm trying to pair using UPnP, is not correct?